# show additional information in legend in flot chart

Tags: flot, rrd

I am using javascriptRRD library to read rrd files and plots graph via float charts. When chart is plotted I only see the legend having color info of value to be plotted . I additional require minimum , maximum, and current values of the data plotted.. is it possible to customize the legend fields ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the data series labels in the legend with a `labelFormatter` function like this:

```
labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
    // series is the series object for the label
    return '<a href="#' + label + '">' + label + '</a>';
}
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend) for more details.

Comment: Beat me to the answer.  @Bhupendra, here's an example I coded up: http://plnkr.co/edit/6uHsRVuJTSbtTjpODKb0?p=preview

Comment: @Mark thanks for demo .In demo legends are stacked one below other in different rows , but in my case it all comes side by side in a single row , is there any flag to change for stacking legends vertically

Comment: @Bhupendra Use `noColumns: 1` (or what you want) in the legend options.